# Avoiding tax complexities of MLPs

Tags: taxes, mutual-funds, etf, accounting, schedule-k-1

I would like to invest in master limited partnerships (MLPs) for their high yield, but would like to avoid their tax complexities.  If I buy exposure to MLPs through an ETF or mutual fund, will that abstract away the need to process individual K-1s and constantly adjust the basis of my holdings, do RoC calculations, etc.?  While these calculations may not be that bad for a single MLP, when you're constantly buying and selling multiple MLPs, the accounting work would seem to be overwhelming.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, MLP ETFs such as AMZA and MLPA eliminate the need to process K-1's yourself.  They handle all the complex tax paperwork for you.

Source: personal experience